# Screen Time: how can I disallow bypassing limits?

Tags: screen-time

It's too easy for me to click on those "one more minute" or "15 minutes" Screen Time bypasses.

Is there a way to really really block apps and websites and not being allowed to bypass the limit at all (unless going to settings etc.)?

I thought at some point there was a way but I cannot find it anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Require a Passcode to bypass Screen Time limits:

`Settings > Screen Time > Use a Screen Time Passcode`

Once this is set, you will need to enter the passcode to bypass the limits. Arrange so that you do not have access to the passcode and you will not be able to bypass the limits.

Comment: Perfect! Asked my spouse to enter a code for me without showing and then asked her to write it down on a secure note I can reach to disable it again if ever necessary.

Comment: @leymannx I wish there was a more secure option than the 4-digit PIN code... https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/372221/screen-time-passcode-use-password-rather-than-4-digit-pin

Answer (score 1):

There does not appear to be a way to disable the option to provide one more minute. That is confirmed at the two threads below.

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250777725

> "Child accounts can click One More Minute once, or click Ask For More Time to send their request to the parent account for approval."

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250882762

> As it turns out, this option cannot be disabled in Settings.

**An Aside:**
Restrictions on vanilla iOS are not very robust. If more restriction and control options are desired, a configuration profile may be created and applied to a "supervised" device. Even then, such a simple thing as enforcing DNS on cell signal is not possible unless you create an always on VPN. App whitelists or blacklists however are possible along with other useful restriction options. You can use the Apple Configurator 2 app on Mac or visit the documentation to see what is possible: https://developer.apple.com/business/documentation/Configuration-Profile-Reference.pdf

Note however that using app whitelist only mode might cause issues with apps not showing up on a connected Apple Watch. I have not been able to find a solution to this.

**Aside Aside:**
I have decided to move to Android as it gives much more control to the user in terms of allowing them to restrict or not restrict what they want. I have taken the iOS restriction options to their limits and they are still found wanting.