# Screen Time Passcode: Use Password rather than 4-digit PIN?

Tags: ios, security, password, screen-time, network

iOS uses a a 4-digit passcode to secure Screen Time settings (formerly known as **Restrictions**).

> #### Use Screen Time Passcode
>
> Use a passcode to secure Screen Time settings, and to allow for more time when limits expire.

I would instead like to use a 20+ character random password that is hard to remember and hard to type. I'll store the password and look it up when necessary, rather than easily accidentally remember the Screen Time passcode.

#### Is there any way to use an alphanumeric password rather than a 4-digit PIN?

---

This is similar to the main iOS device passcode, which **does** allow for more secure input:

> Enter a six-digit passcode. Or tap Passcode Options to switch to a four-digit numeric code, a custom numeric code, or a custom alphanumeric code. [(link)](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204060)

Comment: Did you find a way to do this? Also looking for the same, no idea how to go around it.

Answer (score 6):

I found one workaround for that:

Tell your friend to make a random Passcode and copy-paste it in locked note whose password is copied in another note. It tricks your brain and you just don't want to write password.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, there isn’t a way to use a passcode longer than 4 digits. However, you can use [Password Locker](https://password-locker.com/?ref=applestackexchange) which seems to have been created to solve this problem. It’ll help you enter a 4-digit passcode into your phone in a way you won’t remember it after, and it’ll also store that 4-digit passcode. To retrieve it, you have to go through a tedious 20 min process like counting the number of times the number 2 appears in a list of numbers. The retrieval is annoying enough that you won’t want to go through it to retrieve your passcode, but also your passcode is available for you to retrieve whenever you want to. I’ve been using this for months, and it’s a good solution to your above problem.

Answer (score 1):

Very late to the party but figured out a work-around that I liked:

Generate a random alphanumeric string which acts as instructions for inputting your password. Numbers = numbers, letters = backspace. By the time you’ve reached the end of the 4 digits, you’ve hit backspace too many times to remember which numbers you actually input.

It takes some tweaking of the random generator to actually produce useful strings (ie doesn’t have too many numbers in a row, ect). Or you can just generate a bunch until you see one that looks pretty good.